# How to show canvas in my layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas

Do you know, how to show canvas here:
[image]

What should I put in here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw directly on the canvas using the onDraw method, just create a new class extending View and do your drawing there.
On the xml you put your class as a item on the layout, using the full name of the class including the package.

Example:

```
<com.example.MyCanvas
    android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
    android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
/>
```

Then on your project you have the class MyCanvas on the package com.example that extends View and override the onDraw() where you have a canvas and can draw anything you want on it.

Comment: I don't understand how to put this class in xml ^^ Which object should I put there? Can you give me example?